# How to applyDelta without triggering change Ace Editor

Tags: websocket, ace-editor

I'm trying to sync Ace editor with Websocket, but when i applyDelta (receive by websocket). The on("change") event is trigger. Is there a way to apply changes without triggering events ?

```
socket.onmessage = (data) {
  const deltas = JSON.parse(data);
  editor.applyDeltas(deltas);
}

editor.on("change", (delta) => {
  // here i trigger ws event
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply ignore the events generated by your code

```
var myChange = false
socket.onmessage = (data) {
  const deltas = JSON.parse(data);
  myChange = true
  editor.applyDeltas(deltas);
  myChange = false
}

editor.on("change", (delta) => {
  if (myChange) return
  // here i trigger ws event
});
```